# ColdFusion: how to check if array element exists?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I have to loop over the array of street addresses and insert the data into database. User always provide one line of address and **some times** two.
I am trying to loop the array and dynamically set address_1 and address_2(if exists or NULL if not), but  it does not work for me.

[image: Image of array dump]

Here is what I have:

```
<cfset address_1 = #jsonData.addresses.customer.street[1]#>
<cfif isDefined(jsonData.addresses.customer.street[2])>
    <cfset address_2 = #jsonData.addresses.customer.street[2]#> 
<cfelse>    
    <cfset address_2 = "">
</cfif>
```

When I run it, I get this:
*Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now Suite 300, must be a syntactically valid variable name.*

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error, but ... it's never too early or too late to break the habit of overusing pound `#` signs in CF :-) Sadly a lot of devs, including myself, learned that from the official documentation. Years later I was VERY surprised to learn how infrequently they're actually needed...  Mostly when using `<cfoutput>`, or if a CF variable is wrapped in quotes (that's usually avoidable).  So in the code above, NONE of those pound signs are actually needed :-).

Comment: There's [arrayIsDefined](https://cfdocs.org/arrayisdefined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IsDefined](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/isdefined.html) can only tell you if a variable named `jsonData.addresses.customer.street` exists. It can't examine the contents, so it's the wrong function for this scenario.

Assuming the `street` array always exists, just check it's size using the member function [len()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/using-the-member-functions.html), or [ArrayLen()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraylen.html). If the size is `>= 2`, then you know the 2nd address exists.

```
<!--- Option 1: Member function len()  --->
<cfif jsonData.addresses.customer.street.len() gte 2 > 
   2nd address exists, do something 
</cfif>

<!--- Option 2: ArrayLen() --->
<cfif arrayLen(jsonData.addresses.customer.street) gte 2 > 
   2nd address exists, do something 
</cfif>
```

**Dynamic "address_x" variables**

Depending on what you're ultimately doing, you might consider leaving the address information as an array, because it's easier work with when dealing with a dynamic number of elements. However, if you prefer you could also define separate `address_x` variables dynamically, using  [`<cfloop array="..">`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfloop-looping-over-a-list-a-file-or-an-array.html)

```
<!--- demo data --->
<cfset jsonData.addresses.customer.street = ["Line1","Line2","Line3"]>

<cfloop array="#jsonData.addresses.customer.street#" item="line" index="pos">
    <!--- Use the current position to name variables xx_1, xx_2, xx_3 --->
    <cfset variables["address_"& pos] = line>
</cfloop>

<!--- results --->
<cfdump var="#variables#">
```

**Results:**

[image: Image of generated variables]

---

**About Original Error**

A frequently misunderstood detail about [IsDefined](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/isdefined.html) is that the function expects the *name* of a variable, which is usually a plain string in quotes, like `"myVariable"`. Since there are no quotes surrounding the variable name here:

```
<cfif isDefined( jsonData.addresses.customer.street[2] )>
```

... that variable gets evaluated and its *value* is what's actually being passed into IsDefined(). So the code ends up checking the wrong variable name:

```
<!--- code is really doing this (thinks address[2] is the variable name) --->
<cfif isDefined("Suite 300")>
```

The reason that triggers an error is because `IsDefined()` only accepts [valid CF variable names](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/creating-variables.html). So it can't be used on variable names containing special characters (spaces, square brackets, etc..) - meaning it won't work with a variable named `Suite 300`. That limitation is one of the reasons why [StructKeyExists()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structkeyexists.html) is usually recommended instead.

Comment: Thank you once again. I marked the question as answered (it works), but ... what if I dot not know the number of address fields and I want to dynamically <cfset> as many of them as user enters? This is why I was asking about accessing array by the element.

Comment: I've never used this syntax before: `<cfset variables["address_"& pos] = line>`. I would write it as: `<cfset "address_"pos>`. Is this a preferred way of doing it?

Comment: The first method is called structure notation, and is the preferred way to create dynamic variables, i.e. `someStruct["keyName"] = "foo"`. It forces you to scope your variables, which is a best practice. Since all CF scopes are structures, that syntax can be used with any scope (variables, local, application, etc..).  I've only seen that 2nd syntax in legacy code, ie `<cfset "address_"& pos = "foo">`. Folks used to use it a lot before CF scopes were structures, and it was harder to create dynamic variables.

Answer (score 4):

The Simple Answer to this question  would be to just use ***ArrayIsDefined***

```
<cfif ArrayIsDefined(yourArray, index)>
    <!--- perform your logic here --->
 </cfif>
```

this way you can also prevents the possible errors